# How can I target a text node?

Tags: css

I'm targeting a page with the structure

```
<div class="x">
    <span>This should be visible</span>
    <span>This should be visible</span>
    This shouldn't be.
</div>
```

This is not a page I own, so I can't alter the structure or add tags. I'm just making a custom stylesheet, I can only use CSS.

My first thought was to try

```
div.x { display: none; }
div.x span { display: inline; }
```

But this seems to just hide the entire element regardless.

Comment: Are you only looking to hide the content that shouldn't be visible (or) will you want to do something else with it?

Comment: is this inside a tag *"This shouldn't be."* or just as plain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using** `visibility` **property:**

One approach to hide the the text node content of the element would be to set `visibility: hidden` on the parent `div` and then override it for the `span`.

The downside of using `visibility: hidden` would be that it would leave a blank space if there is any other element after the text node (refer below snippet).

```css
div.x {
  visibility: hidden;
}
div.x span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <span>This should be visible</span>
  <span>This should be visible</span>
  This shouldn't be.
  <span>Some other tag</span>
</div>
```

---

**Using** `font-size` **property:**

Other approach would be to set `font-size: 0px` for the parent and then override it for the `span`.

The downside of this approach is that you need to know what would be the `font-size` of the child elements.

```css
div.x {
  font-size: 0px;
}
div.x span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <span>This should be visible</span>
  <span>This should be visible</span>
  This shouldn't be.
  <span>Some other tag</span>
</div>
```

---

**Using** `color` **property:**

One more approach would be to set `color: transparent` (as Paran0a points out) for the parent and then override it for the `span`.

The downside is that you need to know what the color of the child elements would be and that the text would occupy space because it is still there but is only transparent in color (refer below snippet).

```css
div.x {
  color: transparent;
}
div.x span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <span>This should be visible</span>
  <span>This should be visible</span>
  This shouldn't be.
  <span>Some other tag</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes @Paran0a. It could work but it will be like `visibility: hidden` in the sense that the text would still occupy space.

Comment: God damnit! I was just writing up a similar answer and only just now stack updated the page telling me there was another answer. +1 xD